# Is my tree definitely dead?

Tags: plant-health, citrus

I'll keep this short. I bought a mandarin tree back in March, a few weeks before the Covid-19 outbreak. I kept it in my room in London. It grew a lot of leaves and seemed to do well.

Then I left my flat for over half a year. My flatmate kept watering it for a few more weeks and then forgot. He might have watered it once or twice more in the months after.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now the leaves are yellow/brown and completely dried up although not fallen off. All the branches are brown. Is my tree definitely, 110% dead or is there anything I can do?

Comment: I have never seen a citrus recover from that amount of drought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a sharp knife gently scrape away the bark near the base of the plant. If it shows green, it's alive. If it shows brown, it's dead.

Comment: thanks, this is the kind of answer i was looking for (unfortunately the tree is dead)